# Create a circular line with manipulable edges (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to create a circular line (like a loading spinner) with manipulable edges. It's supposed to be a clock, so one edge will indicate the minutes and the other will indicate the hours (via javascript), but I can't find a way to make both edges independently manipulable.

This is what I have ATM:

HTML

```
<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <circle class="path" cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="none" stroke-width="3">       
    </circle>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.spinner {
    width: 90px;
    height:90px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: block;
}

.spinner .path {
  stroke-dasharray: 40;
  stroke: #7722ff;
}
```

JsF: https://jsfiddle.net/vn5n49rx/1/

I need to be able to change 'edge 1' and 'edge 2' positions from the example below based on a variable value (degrees, pixels, em...). I need to say wherever the edges of the line will start and end.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you be more precise ? maybe show us a screenshot of what you want to obtain

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added and example. Can you see if it helps? I need to be able to change dynamically wherever the line stars or ends (it doesn't need to be using degrees specifically).

Comment: Your JS fiddle example already showing the circle like you mentioned in the example, but in your question, you say you need a arrow like hands of a clock.. !! So what exactly you want, can you post any image of your expectations, you can use paint to create images ..!!

Comment: @ManojShukla I just added an image and an additional explanation.

Comment: You should consider jQuery Knob. https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

Comment: not sure if will help you , i found cool stuff : http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/3404776     i think you should in this example modify  for (i=0; i<numNodes; i++) {   and increase number of dots and i think is waht you are lookin' for

Comment: What about (0) working out the required sweep angle and then (1) the required position of Edge 1. Once done, transform (rotate) the resultant arc? Better yet, since you're using SVG, why bother with circles at all? Here seems like all you'd need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plunker Code updated: --

This plnkr will do the job https://plnkr.co/edit/TpWHdp0KnGpSFo481P8x?p=preview, I've added codes that can be modified easily for dynamic data.

Clicking on button, you can control the behavior.

```
`var deg = 0.0175`
```

this is a simple maths calculation to fit into the circle property of canvas and to make it easy to understand, as we at school learned that values should be in degree.

```js
  var deg = 0.0175;
        var rotateInit = 0; // always clockwise by default; this value is in degree, i.e. 0 degree,
        var angleInit = 45; 
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var disp = document.getElementById("inDegrees");
        
        function draw(rotateVal, angleVal){
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
          ctx.beginPath();
          rotateInit = rotateInit - rotateVal;
          angleInit = angleInit + angleVal;
          
           if (angleInit - rotateInit >= 360) {
             angleInit = 270;
             rotateInit = -90;
            }
            if (angleInit - rotateInit <= 0) {
               angleInit = 0;
               rotateInit = 0;
            }
          var rotate = rotateInit * deg;
          var angle = angleInit * deg;
          ctx.arc(150, 150, 50, rotate, angle);
          disp.innerHTML = 'Current Value in degrees are: '+ (angleInit - rotateInit);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
       

        // function arc(inrValue) {
        //     var newValue = initValue + inrValue;
        //     initValue = newValue;
        //     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        //     ctx.beginPath();
            
        //     ctx.arc(150, 150, 50, left, right);
        //     document.getElementById("inDegrees").innerHTML = 'Current Value in degrees are: '+ initValue;
            
        //     ctx.stroke();
        // }

        function incrementLeft() {
            draw(0, 5); // add 50 degree to current
            console.log("clicked Inr");
        }

        function decrementLeft() {
            draw(0, -5);// sub 50 degree to current
            console.log("clicked Dcr");
        }
        function incrementRight() {
            draw(5, 0); // add 50 degree to current
            console.log("clicked Inr");
        }

        function decrementRight() {
            draw(-5, 0); // sub 50 degree to current
            console.log("clicked Dcr");
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onLoad="draw(0,0)">
    <button onclick="incrementLeft()">+ increment left</button> &nbsp;
    <button onclick="incrementRight()">+ increment right</button> <br>
    <button onclick="decrementLeft()">- decrement left</button> &nbsp;
    <button onclick="decrementRight()">- decrement right</button>
    <p id="inDegrees"></p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" width="300" height="300">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but I need to be able to change both sides of the line, not just one. In your example, I can increment or dec one side, but the other one is always at 0°.

Comment: @Chosmos please look at the updated answer, and try running out the snippet here or in plnkr link. I hope this is what you wanted. :)